# If f(n) is O(g(n)), does f(n) grow asymptotically no faster than g(n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

My quiz had the question:

**"If f(n) is O(g(n)) then f(n) grows asymptotically no faster than g(n), True or False?"**

My understanding is that:

- O(g(n)) is greater than g(n), as it is an upper bound
- f(n) is O(g(n))
- f(n) is greater than g(n)
- f(n) grows faster than g(n)
- so the answer must be FALSE

But the answer turned out to be TRUE, where did I go wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not (yet) a programming question. It is a question about mathematics or the theory of computation.

Comment: The question say "no faster"

Comment: You could use the argument from your first three steps to prove that `g(n)` is greater than itself:  "O(g(n)) is greater than g(n), as it is an upper bound" & "g(n) is O(g(n))" => "g(n) is greater than g(n)" (which is false for all n)). This tells us that at least one part of the premise is false. "g(n) is O(g(n))" is clearly true, so it must be the other one that's false (or rather non-sensical because `O(g(n))` isn't a function).

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning goes like this `O(g(n))` is the set of all functions that asymptotically grow no faster than `g(n)`. When `f(n)` is in this set it therefore grows no faster than `g(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a question of definitions. The big-O symbol has a precise definition (though it's sometimes defined in different ways, but I think your learning material explicitly picked one precise definition out of a few widely used ones), so you can always look at it.

But the phrase "X grows asymptotically no faster than Y" is not so clear. Do you have it defined somewhere? If yes, does it say `X = O(Y)`? If so, here is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Asymptotic upper bound, we use O-notation.

O(g(n)) = f(n) : 0 <= f(n) <= cg(n) for all n>=n0.

function f(n) is members of O(g(n)).
c and n0 are constants.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in comparing O(g(n)) directly to g(n), as big O describes rate of growth and g(n) is a function, so the two cannot be directly compared.

The question is true basically by definition: the upper bound of its rate of growth is equal to the rate of growth of g(n), so it could not possibly grow any faster than g(n).

Answer (score 0):

Let's first pick a specific definition since you aren't really providing us with one.

From Sipser's *Introduction to The Theory of Computation*

> Let *f* and *g* be functions such that *f*, *g* : *N* → *R*+
>
> Say that *f(n)* = *O( g(n) )* if positive integers *c* and *m* exist such
>   that for every integer *n* ≥ *m*, *f(n)* ≤ *cg(n)*

According to this definition, *f(n)* **can** grow faster than plain old *g(n)* so your conclusion isn't wrong!

BUT there's a catch, and it involves the word **asymptotically**.

For *f(n)* to grow **asymptotically** faster than *g(n)* it needs to be able to "overtake" all functions of the form 1 * *g(n)*, 2 * *g(n)*, 3 * *g(n)*, ..., 1,000,000 * *g(n)*, ... at some or the other value of *n*.

An example might be helpful.

The function *f(n) = 3n + 1* definitely grows faster than *n*, but it's obvious that *f(n) ≤ 10n* for all *n > 0* so according to the defintion above *f(n) = O(n)*